# Windows 7 compatibility mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows, delphi

I have an application written in Delphi XE5 that targets mainly Windows 7, but also Windows 8 and 8.1. It does require that the user has administrator rights.

It works fine on nearly all of my user's computers, but on a few it only works when selecting compatibility mode for Windows 7 in Windows 7.

The error presents itself directly when starting up the application as a windows dialog stating that:

```
[NameOfMyProgram] has stopped working.
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18839
Exception code: 0eedfade
```

My question is the following: Why is there a compatibility mode for Windows 7 on Windows 7, and what does it mean to use this mode that could affect my application in the way described above?

I have not been able to find any documentation about this specific compatibility mode.

Comment: Why does your program require admin rights? Your exception is an unhandled Delphi exception. Were you to add madExcept (or similar) you'd know what raised the exception. That would be the right way to debug the problem if you can't actually attach a debugger to it.

Comment: What does your app actually do with its admin rights? Are you running it with elevated privileges? What is your app doing at the moment it crashes?

Comment: @Jerry What it is doing is failing to startup, as stated. The asker doesn't know because the app won't have displayed any UI yet.

Comment: @David It is a large application that contains a lot of old legacy code. I try to reduce the number of operations that require admin rights with every new release, but a lot of work still remains.

Comment: If I were you I'd try to fix the real problem rather than worry about compat modes. In other words, I would not have asked this question. Step 1, identify the cause of the unhandled exception.

Comment: @David I am using Eurekalog, not sure why it does not manage to display the normal dialog that is shown at other times when exceptions occur. I have not used madExcept, how does that tool compare to Eurekalog?

Comment: Install application compatibility toolkit. Run compatibility manager. Select compatibility modes from the tree. Select Win7RTM. On the right side you'll find applied shims (elevatecreateprocess, emulatesortingvista, ...).  Find explanations [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722305%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: @David I agree, the reason why I am asking about compatibility modes is to understand what it does, in order to perhaps be able to better pinpoint the location of the error. It was one user that came up with this "solution", not my idea...

Comment: I'd guess that madExcept won't succeed where EurekaLog fails. Can you debug this?

Comment: For pinpointing this, I don't think knowing more about compat will likely help. You've got a runtime Delphi exception raised. You should be able to find the source of that exception. That would then give you the route to solving the problem.

Comment: @David Unfortunately I do not have access to a single computer where it fails. It only happens for users employed at a specific customer company. However, they are located on another continent, so I cannot easily test it myself.

Comment: @Torbjorn - I doubt it will help but for your convenience here's the full list:  ElevateCreateProcess 
EmulateSortingVista 
FailObsoleteShellAPIs 
FaultTolerantHeap 
GlobalMemoryStatus2GB 
HandleBadPtr 
NoGhost 
RedirectBDE 
RedirectMP3Codec 
SyncSystemAndSystem32 
VirtualRegistry 
Win7RTMVersionLie 
WRPDllRegister 
WRPMitigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're running Windows 7, the "Windows 7" option appears on the compatibility list when you have Windows 7 SP1 installed. If you don't have SP1 installed, then that option will not appear on the list.

The option makes Windows appear to the program as though it does not have the service pack installed, which may affect the behavior of certain API functions.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense